# Passport JWT : req.user is always Unauthorized

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, passport.js, passport-jwt

I have searched similar question on stack overflow , but any of one is not working for me , so i ask this question again.

I am using [passport-jwt](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-jwt/) to with `express`.

> I want to get logged in user id , to store it in other model. but every time I get 401 Unauthorized

here is **helpers/passport.js**

```
const options = {};
options.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();

options.secretOrKey = configuration.secret_key.JWTsecretkey;

module.exports = passport => {
  passport.use(
    new JwtStrategy(options, (jwt_payload, done) => {
      console.log('jwt_payload ==',jwt_payload);
      User.findById(jwt_payload.id)
        .then(user => {
          if (user) {
            return done(null, user);
          }
          return done(null, false);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
          return done(err, false);
        });
    })
  );
};
```

here is **server.js**

```
global.express = require('express');
global.app = express();
global.passport = require('passport');
global.jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
global.JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
global.ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
global.requireTree = require('require-tree')
global.controllers = requireTree(rootdir+'/controllers')
global.routes=requireTree(rootdir+'/routes')
global.helpers = requireTree(rootdir + '/helpers')

app.use(passport.initialize())
require(rootdir+'/helpers/passport')(passport)

app.use('/api/auth',routes.api.auth);

app.listen(8888)
```

**routes/api/auth.js**

```
 const router=express.Router();

 router.get('/user', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),controllers.auth.user);
  module.exports =router
```

**controllers/auth/user.js**

```
module.exports=(req,res)=>{
    res.json({
        user:req.user
      });
}
```

When I tried with postman but not working .

[image]

I have also tried with : `ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('jwt')` 
   as it is upvoted in some questions , but it is not working .

I am using

> "passport": "^0.4.0" ,
>    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0" ,
>    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0"

please help me to solve this problem .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have solved above errors by replacing
>   `User.findById(jwt_payload.id)` with
>   `User.findById(jwt_payload._id)`

here is updated **passport.js**

```
const options = {};
options.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
options.secretOrKey = configuration.secret_key.JWTsecretkey;

module.exports = passport => {
  passport.use(
    new JwtStrategy(options, (jwt_payload, done) => {
      console.log('jwt_payload ==',jwt_payload);
      User.findById(jwt_payload._id)
        .then(user => {
          if (user) {
            return done(null, user);
          }
          return done(null, false);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
          return done(err, false);
        });
    })
  );
};
```